# Event in Maya Api to capture currentTime / frame change

Tags: c++, events, callback, message, maya

I am currently developing a Maya plugin. How can I set-up a callback that gets fired each time the frame number / current time is changed in the scene ?
I had a look at the MSceneMessage Class, but it doesn't seem to contain what I am looking for.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MEventMessage` to setup a callback every time frame/current time changes. Code speaks louder than words, so here's some code with comments interspersed to illustrate how to set this up: (TLDR for the impatient first, full code excerpt will follow in the next section)

## TLDR:

A code summary for the impatient:

```
    // ...

    // Our callback Id array to 
    // store the Ids of all our callbacks
    // for later removal    
    MCallbackIdArray myCallbackIds;

    // This is where the actual adding callback happens
    // We register our callback to the "timeChanged" event
    MCallbackId callbackId = MEventMessage::addEventCallback("timeChanged",  (MMessage::MBasicFunction) MySampleCmd::userCB);

    // ...

    if(myCallbackIds.length() != 0)
        // Make sure we remove all the callbacks we added
        stat = MEventMessage::removeCallbacks(myCallbackIds);
```

- Reference for [MEventMessage from the docs](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2009help/API/class_m_event_message.html#c038e5bbbfc19b2772d1a01220b570c0).
- The events listed [here](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2009help/Commands/scriptJob.html#flaglistEvents) (in the `scriptJob` command) can be used with the `MEventMessage`.

---

## Full(ish) code with comments:

### MySampleCommand.h

```
class MySampleCmd : public MPxCommand {
public:
                MySampleCmd();
    virtual     ~MySampleCmd();

    // Our callback - implemented as a static method
    static      void userCB(void* clientData);

    MStatus     doIt( const MArgList& );
    MStatus     redoIt();
    MStatus     undoIt();   
    bool        isUndoable() const;
    static      void* creator();

public:

    // Our callback Id array to 
    // store the Ids of all our callbacks
    // for later removal
    MCallbackIdArray myCallbackIds;
};
```

## MySampleCommand.cpp (Excerpt)

```
// Constructor
MySampleCmd::MySampleCmd() {

    // Clearing our callback Id array
    // for housekeeping    
    myCallbackIds.clear();
}

// Destructor
MySampleCmd::~MySampleCmd() {

    // Make sure we remove all the callbacks we added
    // Failing to do so will result in fatal error    
    if(myCallbackIds.length() != 0)

        // Remove the MEventMessage callback
        MEventMessage::removeCallbacks(myCallbackIds);
}

MStatus MySampleCmd::redoIt() {

    // This is where the actual adding callback happens
    // We register our callback to the "timeChanged" event
    MCallbackId callbackId = MEventMessage::addEventCallback("timeChanged",  (MMessage::MBasicFunction) MySampleCmd::userCB);

    // Append the newly added callback's ID to our list of callback ids
    // for future removal
    myCallbackIds.append(callbackId);
    return MS::kSuccess;
}

MStatus MySampleCmd::undoIt() {
    MStatus stat;
    if(myCallbackIds.length() != 0)
        // Make sure we remove all the callbacks we added
        stat = MEventMessage::removeCallbacks(myCallbackIds);
    return stat;
}

// Our callback function
void SafeSelect::userCB(void* clientData) {
    MGlobal::displayInfo( "Callback userCB called!\n" );
    return;
}
```

Comment: Complementary question: Is there a way to have "userCB" not being a static function ? I would like to call a non-static function in the same class. Thanks.

Comment: Is the plugin you are building a node, a Deformer, or a command? What kind of plugin is it?

Comment: It's a node. But I think I found out a solution. I am sending the current Class (this) as 3rd argument in the addEventCallback, and receive this class in the userCB that I can then access.

Comment: That almost seems like the only viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Also, depending on the application, you can just create an expression which calls arbitray python/mel (including an MPXCommand from your plugin).

Comment: Depending on the use case, this could be a more modularised solution.